# Performance of Rust vector (`Vec<T>`) versus array (`[T; n]`)

Tags: arrays, vector, rust

How much am I losing in terms of performance when using a vector versus an array in Rust?

By performance I mean: speed of element access or speed of iteration.

Answer (score 44):

They both store data in a linear contiguous array where accessing or iterating is both an O(1) operation so there's no difference in performance. The only case when vector is slower is probably for some small lists because array is stored on stack in the current stack frame, hence their data is highly probably already loaded to the CPU cache. Vector OTOH stores data on the heap so data will not be available in cache before they're first accessed

Vector also has one more level of redirection because you need to load the address of the array first so the first memory access may also be slower, but that's just negligible

The other time when vector is much worse is when you use a vector of vector vs a multidimensional array because each vector is allocated separately and lies all around memory which is not good for caching. See [Access time of vec vs array](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3bu7a8/access_time_of_vec_vs_array/)

See also [Difference between array vs. vec for memory and cpu usage](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/difference-between-array-vs-vec-for-memory-and-cpu-usage/23710/2)

Comment: array on stack are slower because of stack protection. Yes, this is counter intuitive. The only vec problem is allocation time and if you coded right it's not a problem and it's not the scope of this question.

Comment: @Stargateur Does Rust usually compile code with specific buffer overflow protection for stack variables? I doubt that this is true. Safe code in Rust is memory safe by default, and all index accesses are checked regardless of whether the array you are indexing into is on the stack or the heap.

Comment: @SvenMarnach The language is irrelevant a lot of Rust code rely on external lib that will maybe corrupt the stack, but yes rust have this option (llvm), add the possible protection from OS. There is really few reason to use array over vector, in real world application stack will be slower more dangerous and less flexible. Stack should only be use for small array, not buffer.

Comment: @Stargateur We seem to be talking about different things. I was referring to to software stack protection à la `-fstack-protector-all`, which emits additional code to detect buffer overflows, and is unrelated to the OS as far as I am aware. This kind of protection doesn't make too much sense in Rust, since it won't help with any C libraries we link against and does not offer any additional benefits over Rust's standard memory safety features. You seem to be referring to a different "stack protection" that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Nested vecs vs. 1D arrays doesn't always involve a performance difference. I was surprised by this! I wrote a ray tracer which stores the 2D pixel grid. Benchmarking showed zero difference between storing the 2D grid in a 1D array and a vec-inside-vec.